# Does zero acceleration also implies zero Force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

As we know by $Newton's$ $1st$ $law$ that *$F$ $=$ $0$ $implies$ $a$ $=$ $0$* but while performing experiments for $Newton's$ $2nd$ $law$ we assume that the body on which we are performing the experiment is on an inertial frame and the net Force on the body is *zero*. But my question is that, how do we make sure that the net force on the body is actually *zero* as Newton's 1st law only tells that *$F$ $=$ $0$ $implies$ a $=$ $0$* but doesn't explains anything about what *$a$ = 0* $implies$ $($or does *a $=$ $0$ $implies$ $F$ $=$ $0$* $)$. So how do we make sure that the net force on the body is actually *zero*. We may know that the net force on the system/body is *zero* since we know the 2nd law at the present time, but I am asking how do we know, if we don't know the $2nd$ $law$ of motion yet like at the time of $Newton$, like assume that we are Newton and don't know much about the forces.

Comment: Your last sentence is a doozy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As we know by Newton's 1st law ... but while performing experiments for Newton's 2nd law we assume that the body on which we are performing the experiment is on an inertial frame and the net Force on the body is zero.

Well, for starters, the things you state as assumptions are not necessarily true as one could perform an experiment for the so-called "second law" in both inertial and non-inertial frames of reference. This is where one needs to be careful in their analysis as one needs to factor in the relative motion of the frames appropriately in order to verify their results.

> how do we make sure that the net force on the body is actually zero as Newton's 1st law only tells that F = 0 implies a = 0 but doesn't explains anything about what a = 0 implies (or does a=0 implies F=0). So how do we make sure that the net force on the body is actually zero.

Let us recall Newton's first law - *"Every body continues in its state of rest, or of uniform motion in a straight line, unless it is compelled to change that state by forces impressed upon it."* (Translated from Latin)

In your language, this is the statement, $F = 0 \implies a = 0$. This is indeed correct. More precisely, the first law is equivalent to, $a = 0 \impliedby \neg (F \neq 0)$. This means that $a = 0$ is *necessary* for $F =0$, but not *sufficient*. However, this is only true for $m \neq 0$, which is typically satisfied for simple mechanical experiments, eg. pendulum bob. *Sufficiency* is guaranteed only by the second law $(F = ma)$ for non-zero masses. In fact, the second law reduces to $m \neq 0 \implies (F = 0 \iff a = 0)$ for constant $m$.

> So how do we make sure that the net force on the body is actually zero. We may know that the net force on the system is zero since we know the 2nd law at present time but I am asking how do we know if we don't know 2nd law of motion yet like at the time of Newton, like assume that we are Newton and don't know much about the forces.

Ensuring $F = 0$ is therefore not possible by virtue of Newton's first law alone. In fact, it is practically impossible. However, say you perform the experiment and get some results and compare it against the theory of $F = ma$. The experimental error reflects all the factors that were ignored in the procedure. Significant factors would give you very large error, in which case either the conditions aren't suitable for your experiment, or the theory is wrong. Instead of comparing with a theory, one could also repeat the experiment in different, but consistent conditions to determine the second law.

Answer (score 2):

If the body is not accelerating then the net force is $0$ (assuming constant mass). However this is not the same as saying that *no forces act on the body*. A net force of $0$ can be accomplished by having two identical forces in magnitude act in opposite directions, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> But my question is that, how do we make sure that the net force on the body is actually zero as Newton's 1st law only tells that F = 0 implies a = 0 but doesn't explains anything about what a = 0 implies( or does a=0 imples F=0)

With $\vec F_{net}=m\vec a$ if we know $\vec F_{net}=0$ then either: $$0=m\vec a \rightarrow \vec a=0$$or$$0=m\vec a \rightarrow m=0$$

On the other hand, if we know $\vec a=0$ then: $$\vec F_{net}=m \ 0 \rightarrow \vec F_{net}=0$$

So in fact $\vec a=0$ does imply $\vec F_{net}=0$, while $\vec F_{net}=0$ does not imply $\vec a=0$.

> how do we know if we don't know 2nd law of motion yet, like assume that we are Newton and don't know much about the forces

That part is more like a question about historical fiction than physics.

Comment: All massless particles move at $c$, so Newton's 2nd Law only applies to objects with non-zero mass.  Thus, $F_{net}=0$ does imply that $a=0$.

Comment: The question was asked and answered in the context of Newtonian physics where we often have “massless” ropes and springs that do not move at c and do accelerate